# Mi formulario No funciona en Hosting

Tags: ajax, formularios

Estoy trabajando con un formulario utilizando ajax. En local utilizando wampserver hace mis registros con exito. Estoy haciendo pruebas en un hosting y no me hace ninguna operacion.

```
//codigo JS

$(function(){
$('#registrar').click(function(){
  var numcontrol = $('#numcontrol').val();
  var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
  var apellido = $('#apellido').val();
  var sexo = $('#sexo').val();
  var domicilio = $('#domicilio').val();
  var edad = $('#edad').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var carrera = $('#carrera').val();
  var pass1 = $('#contra1').val();
  var pass2 = $('#contra2').val();

    if (numcontrol!=='' && nombre!=='' && apellido !==''&& sexo !=='' && domicilio !=='' && edad!=='' &&email !=='' && pass1 !==''&& pass2!=='') {
       $.ajax({
         url : '../php/registro.php',
         method : 'POST',
         data : {
           'numcontrol' : numcontrol,
          'nombre' : nombre,
          'apellido' : apellido,
          'sexo' : sexo,
          'domicilio' : domicilio,
          'edad' : edad,
          'email': email,
          'carrera': carrera,
          'contra1' : pass1,
          'contra2' : pass2
        },
         success: function(msg){
           if (msg == '1') {
             $('#msg').html('Ya existe usuario').css("background-color", "#ff6347");
           }else if(msg == '2'){

            $('#msg').html('Datos registrados ').css("background-color", "#1AB667");

        }else if(msg == '3'){
               $('#msg').html('No coincide Contraseña').css("background-color", "#ff6347");
        }else if(msg=='4'){
          $('#msg').html('error al registrar ').css("background-color", "#ff6347");
        }
         }
       });
    }else {
      $('#msg').html('Ingrese datos').css("background-color", "#ff6347");
    }
});
});

//codigo  PHP 'registro.php'
<?php

 require('conexion.php');
$numcontrol = $_POST['numcontrol'];
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
 $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
 $domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
 $edad = $_POST['edad'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
  $carrera = $_POST['carrera'];
 $pass1 = $_POST['contra1'];
 $pass2 = $_POST['contra2'];

$registro = new conexion();
$registro -> registrarAlumno($numcontrol,$nombre,$apellido,$sexo,$domicilio,$edad, $email,$carrera,$pass1, $pass2 );
$registro -> cerrar();

 ?>

//metodo Registrar 
  function registrarAlumno($numcontrol,$nombre,$apellido,$sexo,$domicilio,$edad, $email,$carrera,$pass1, $pass2){
      //comparacion si contraseña 1 es igual a la segunda
      //contraseña ingresad
      if($pass1 == $pass2){
        //si es igual crear una variable
        //booleana igual a true
          $validacion_pass = true;
      }else{
        //en caso contrario es false
          $validacion_pass= false;
      }
     //si validacion_pass es igual true
     //es decir las dos contraseñas son iguales
      if($validacion_pass){
         //hacer la seleccion del nombre del usuario
         // de la tabla  usuario y comparar si es igual
          $consult = $this->conexion->query("SELECT * from alumno where     num_control = '".$numcontrol."'");
          //si en la base de  datos encuentra mas de dos datos
          //que coinciden con ese nombre
          if(mysqli_num_rows($consult)> 0){
              echo '1';
          }else{
   //en caso contrario puede insertar el nuevo usuario

    $query =  "INSERT into alumno(num_control,Nombre,Apellidos,sexo,domicilio,edad,email,contra,id_carrera,id_cargo )  values('".$numcontrol."', '".$nombre."', '".$apellido."','".$sexo."', '".$domicilio."','".$edad."','".$email."','".$pass1."','".$carrera."', 1)";
            $consulta = $this->conexion->query($query);
            if($consulta){
                    echo "2";
                  }else{
                    echo "4";
                  }

                    }
      }else{
          echo '3';
      }
    }
```

Comment: veo que en tu ajax señalas que el archivo php está en otra carpeta, pero si estás añadiendo el ajax en tu página base osea el index deberías hacerlo así php/registro.php y no así ../php/registro.php

Answer (score 2):

Como no mencionas qué pruebas has hecho y si has descartado posibles errores, podrías empezar por asegurarte que los php están en las ruta adecuada.

Si todo está donde debería, prueba activando `error_reporting(E_ALL);` en el fichero php a ver si muestra algún error.

También podrás comprobar los logs del servidor a ver si tienes "algo" allí.

O depurar el javascript con las herramientas para desarrolladores del navegador a ver si tienes algún error.

Saludos!